# How can I remove "Connect to TFS" from the Visual Studio 2012 Start Page?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I start Visual Studio 2012 RC, the Start page has these items:

- Connect to TFS...
- New Project...
- Open Project...

I don't use TFS.  I use Git.  Is there a way I can remove that "Connect to TFS" so I don't have to see it every time I run VS 2012?

Comment: With Visual Studio 2012 Update 1, it appears that at least they've moved `Connect to TFS` *below* the `New/Open Project` options instead of above them as it used to be.  This makes it slightly less obnoxious.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You might be able to go to Tool\Options, select the Source Control item in the left hand side, and change the Current source control plug-in to "None".</s>

It appears this is a design decision--a way to bring light to Express-version features. Someone has logged this as a Connect issue where you can vote on it: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750913/start-page-shows-connect-to-tfs-server

Comment: It appears this is a design decision--a way to bring light to Express-version features.  Someone has logged this as a Connect issue where you can vote on it: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750913/start-page-shows-connect-to-tfs-server

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Custom Start Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa991992%28VS.110%29.aspx).